# Data missing error when using Carbon::createFromFormat in laravel [dateFormat: year-month]

Tags: ajax, laravel, pdf, php-carbon

I'm getting "Data Missing" error when using Carbon to pass data to pdf view in Laravel.
The query work when the data is pass back to the same page with dropdown list but getting error when pass to another page.

the error that i get
[image]

I'm using date picker as my dropdown list & the date format that I'm using is:
`"2020-December"`

ajax:

```
                changeMonth:true,
                changeYear:true,
                showButtonPanel:true,
                dateFormat: "yy-MM",
 
            onClose: function(dateText, inst) {  
                var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val(); 
                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val(); 
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1)); 
              }
            });

 $('#convertBtn').click(function() {     
                var s = document.getElementById("sites");
                var site = s.options[s.selectedIndex].text;
                var startdate = $('#datepicker-8').val();

            if(site != '' && startdate  != '' )
            {  
                $.ajax({ 
                    paging: false,
                    searching: false, 
                    processing: true,
                    retrieve: true,
                    serverSide: true,
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                    url:"{{ route('billing.bill') }}",
                    type:"GET",
                    dataType:"json",
                    data:{
                        site:site, 
                        startdate:startdate,
                        },
                    
                    success:function(data){
                     alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                     
                    },
                    error: function(data){
                        alert('Error');
                    }
                }) 
            } 
            else
            {
                alert("Please select 'Site' & 'Date'. ");
            }
        });
```

controller

```
$sites['report_date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-F', $request->startdate);
        $data = DB::table('monthly_data')
                ->where('site', $request->site)
                ->whereMonth('report_date', $sites['report_date'])
                ->whereYear('report_date',$sites['report_date'])
                ->get();

        $pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
        $pdf -> loadView('pdf',compact('data'));
        $pdf -> setPaper('a4','landscape');
        return $pdf->stream('report.pdf');
```

may i know how to solve this error?

Comment: try `dd($request->startdate)` and post what format your getting in controller and try to add validation as well

Comment: @KamleshPaul tried ```dd($request->startdate)``` it give the same error "Data Missing"

Comment: before error occur  use `dd()`

Comment: Use `dd($request->startdate)` as the first line in the controller method and see what you are getting

Comment: @KamleshPaul  @Donkarnash   i get null from ```dd($request->startdate)``` is it my ajax failed to pass the data to controller? or that's problem with my query?

Comment: yes that's the problem fix that and add validation so you will not get 500 error

Comment: @KamleshPaul i tried dd($request) and i get null too. i'm wondering whether i did any mistake on my ajax and it cant pass to controller.  That's something weird is i have one filter button and i can using the same query to get the data i want.

Comment: remove these `paging: false,
                    searching: false, 
                    processing: true,
                    retrieve: true,
                    serverSide: true,` from ajax

Comment: @KamleshPaul removed. it still getting null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution:
do some changes in ajax

```
 
                data: {
                    site: site,
                    startdate: startdate,
                },
                xhrFields: {
                    responseType: 'blob' // to avoid binary data being mangled on charset conversion
                },
                success: function(blob, status, xhr) {

                    var ieEDGE = navigator.userAgent.match('/Edge/g');
                    var ie = navigator.userAgent.match('/.NET/g'); // IE 11+
                    var oldIE = navigator.userAgent.match('/MSIE/g');

                    if (ie || oldIE || ieEDGE) {
                        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
                    } else {
                        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        document.write('<iframe src="' + fileURL + '" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
                    }

                },
                error: function(data) {
                    alert('Error');
                }
```

remove `dataType:"json";` and replace it with  `xhrFields: { responseType: 'blob'}`   then it works